# Handlebars lookup object using key from array?

Tags: handlebars.js, lookup

I have an object with an array and an object. I iterate the array (fields) - using it as a template to create form elements. I want to - in the process - get the corresponding object value from the object (data).

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "int",
            "max_length": 11,
        },
        {
            "name": "email",
            "type": "varchar",
            "max_length": 191,
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "id": "4",
        "email": "person@domain.com",
    }
}
```

Something like this (mind map):

```
{{#each fields}}
    <li>
        lookup {{lookup ../data => VALUE OF CORRESPONDING KEY ("id" or "email" etc.)}}
        <label for="{{name}}">{{CamelCase name}}</label>
        {{InputType name type}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

So, when the field name is 'id' I'd like to grab the value of 'id' from the object etc.

I can't seem to wrap my head around the lookup ... or are there some other more clever and direct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you summarized the desired logic very well when you said "when the field name is 'id' I'd like to grab the value of 'id' from the object".

In other words, you want to perform a `lookup` on the `data` Object and the value of the `name` variable is the key to be looked up.

The lookup would be simply: `{{lookup ../data name}}`. `name` will evaluate to the desired key to be looked-up on the context object `../data`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, ended up doing this (passing the data to the helper):

```
{{#each fields}}
    <li>
        <label for="{{name}}">{{CamelCase name}}</label>
        {{InputType name type ../data }}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

And then in the helper extracted the value by doing:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("InputType", function ( name, type, value) {
    switch ( type ) { …
    … value="' + value[name] + '">');
```